# How to remove a string that contains special chars from many files

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed

I need to remove (replace by blank) a string from all files in a directory and sub-directories.

However this string contains specials chars such as &?.<>/
(it is an url)! 
I tried with sed and with rpl with no success: no way to escape the chars.
ex of string to be changes

```
<script src='https://test.com?type=in2&frm=scr&'></script>
```

When trying with

```
 rpl " <script src='https://test.com?type=in2&frm=scr&'></script>" "" index.php
```

I got an error;
NameError: name 'raw_input' is not defined

I just need to know how to escape these '/?.& chars in sed of in rpl

Comment: What does your ideal outcome look like in this example?

Comment: it replaces that string by empty string ""

Comment: So would your outcome just be: `<script src="https://test.com"></script>`?

Comment: No: it should DELETE the whole script line.

Comment: In your question you say you want to replace the string with a blank then in one comment you say you want to replace the string with an empty string and then in yet another comment you say you want to delete the whole line containing the string. Which is it? [edit] your question to include concise, testable sample input and expected output to help clarify your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Use find with sed:

```
find /dir/*  -exec sed -i 's/&//g;s/\?//g;s/\<//g;s/\>//g;s/\///g' {} +
```

to change line:

```
grep -v "<script src='https://test.com?type=in2&frm=scr&'></script>" file > newfile
```

Comment: I dont need a regex: the line I want to remove is EXACTLY this one !

Answer (score 0):

> it should DELETE the whole script line.

Use `grep` with `-v` then.

```
$ cat <<'EOF' >/tmp/test.txt
a
<script src='https://test.com?type=in2&frm=scr&'></script>
b
EOF
$ grep -x -v "<script src='https://test.com?type=in2&frm=scr&'></script>" /tmp/test.txt
a
b
```

Comment: Add `-F` so you don't need to escape the BRE metachars like `.`.